# How to switch to another event after first event was ran?

Tags: angular, dom-events

I have a function in my angular 4 app which listens to `blur` event.

```
<input type="password" (blur)="validate()"/>
```

The problem user has to click away to get an error and do that after changing the password to meet the requirements.

Listening just to `keyup` from the start will show the error even if the user haven't finished typing yet, which is unnecessary.

So, I would like to run `blur` the first time, so the user could go back and edit the value, but the second time it would listen to `keyup` event, so the user could see instantly if the value met the password requirements.

What would be the best way to achieve this in angular 4 ++ ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the change event:

`<input type="password" (change)="validate()"/>`